# Why does $\text{Var}(v^T X) = 0$ imply one random variable is a linear combination of the others?

Tags: probability

I am trying to follow the proof of proposition 4.6.8 in [Guy Lebanon's book](http://theanalysisofdata.com/probability/4_6.html).

So he claims $\text{Var}(v^T X) = 0$ (assuming $v \ne 0$) implies $v^T X$ is a deterministic random varaible (makes sense to me). But then he concludes: *This can only happen if one component of X is a linear combination of the other components.* I don't understand why.

If $v^T X$ is a deterministic variable, it takes *some* constant value - call it $y$. Then, we'd have $v^T X = \sum_i v_i X_i = y$.

Isn't it the case that we can at best prove that $X_j = y - \sum_{i \ne j} v_i X_i$? But that does not make $X_j$ a linear combination of the other variables unless $y = 0$, which we cannot guarantee.

Comment: I think you are right. Either the author is taking "linear" to mean "affine", or has some other hidden assumption such as $EX_i=0, \forall i$

Comment: @kimchilover something similar is said [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498395/variance-covariance-matrix-positive-definiteness) and also elsewhere online though.

Comment: The answer by Stefan to that question changes the definition of $\Sigma$ slightly, to $E[XX^T]$ instead of $\operatorname{Var}(X)$; with that change his use of "linear" is correct.

Comment: Ok, so I think that you're right.